# Select Button and AJAX sourced data

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am working on a datatables implementation. I have an AJAX sourced datatable, however, some content of the returned array are IDs and I would like to show the real values of these ID in a select box. But the returned object doesn't return the real values. Is there a way to combine different ajaxsource to fill one datatable and how do I fill the select button.

I have a sample code on JS Fiddle.

Comment: the fiddle link is  http://jsfiddle.net/aadewojo/oz24emd4/

Comment: here is the same fiddle without errors, also added Query and dataTables :) -> **http://jsfiddle.net/9pty5hos/** Now there only lack some test data :)

Comment: Generally, I believe questions has a much, much better chance for being understanded and answered if they contain the code in question themselves. Code is need to have, a fiddle is nice to have :)

Comment: Hi Thanks, but my question hasn't been answered. I like to know howw to return the real values in a dropdown list box.